# Calling protected variable from another class

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement, variables, methods, protected

I need to call a protected variable from a public class into an if statement in a private method of another public class
I am programing a video game in unity and I need to use a bool variable (that shows if the character is out of stamina) in an if statement to determine whether or not the character can run
This is what my code looks like excluding everything unrelated to the problem

```
Public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerialzeField] protected bool Tired;
}

Public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
Private void HandleRunning()
 {
 If (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && X != True) 
  {
 Speed = RunSpeed;
  }
 }
}
X is where I want the Tired variable to be.
```

Comment: Make it either `protected internal` or add a public getter method or read-only property, latter being the best.

Comment: Making it protected internal gives me the error
CS0120:An object reference is required for the non -static field, method, or property 'Characterstats.Tired'
Admitably I have never (or know how to) added a read only property
I also don't know about the public getter method I can add one but don't know what to do in it

Comment: The general consensus is that you should be using `[SerialzeField] private bool foo;` _explicitly for the Unity Editor_ and `public bool Foo => foo;` for _everything else_ in your code

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`public` readonly **property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like e.g.

```c#
public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Keep you serialized field protected
    [SerialzeField] protected bool tired;

    // Have a public read-only accessor property
    public bool Tired => tired;
}
```

and then e.g.

```c#
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Somehow you will need to get a reference to the CharacterStats instance
    // e.g. via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private CharacterStats stats;

    [SerializeField] private float RunSpeed;

    private float Speed;

    private void HandleRunning()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && !stats.IsTired) 
       {
           Speed = RunSpeed;
       }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively (and my apologies to @aybe who had answered this) you can actually directly serialize a property using explicitely

```c#
[field: SerializeField] public bool Tired { get; protected set; }
```

this is a property which can be accessed by everyone but only this and inherited classes (and due to the serialization now the Inspector) have the permission to set the value.

---

In general: Fix your casing! In `c#` all keywords are lower key!

Comment: @aybe I indeed stand corrected, my bad! I had no idea that you could force the direct serialization of properties using `[field: SerializeField]` .. please undelete your anwer ;)

Comment: As a parallel to this (derHugo probably knows this one already, but for future readers...), you can force the *non-* serialisation (and hide in editor) of a public field using ```[System.NonSerialized]```

Comment: @Immersive I'm pretty sure though that in this case the serialization is explicitely desired in order to save it and configure it in the Inspector ... otherwise you would use only the property without a backing field in the first place ;)

Comment: True!  I tend to use Odin a lot, which exposes properties via the editor, so I occasionally need to explicitly disable fields & properties.